# Vim - How to keep scrolling automatically up or down until I stop it (without any plugin)

Tags: vim

I want to give a command to start scrolling window automatically up or down until I stop it using any key press or any other command. I want to do it without installing any plugin.

Comment: Could you please tell me the reason why you need this? Can't you just hold the `j` & `k` button to do it?

Comment: I want to auto scroll lyrics @wlisrausr

Comment: Maybe you can use a different tool for this purpose. Don't use Vim. Just my 2 cents :)

Comment: One for https://vi.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You can scroll with these commands from the command line:

```
:while 1 | let c=getchar(1) | if c != 0 | break | else | exec "norm! gj" | sleep 60 m | redraw | endif | endwhile
```

The scrolling will end when you press any key. You can adjust the speed by changing the sleep parameter.

You can create a command:

```
:command Scroll while 1 | let c=getchar(1) | if c != 0 | break | else | exec "norm! gj" | sleep 60 m | redraw | endif | endwhile
```

and then use

```
:Scroll
```

Comment: works like magic. i have done some modification 
"while 1 | exec "norm gj"| sleep 60 m |redraw | endwhile"
ctrl + c to stop it ctrl +s pause the screen ctrl + q resume the screen

Answer (score 1):

Adjust this script to your liking, for example increase `s:timer_msec` and set a more suitable mapping. Save it e.g. as `vim/plugin/lyrics/lyrics.vim`.

```vim
func! s:handler(timer)
  exec "norm! \<C-e>"
endfunc

func! AutoScrollToggle()
  if !exists("s:scroll_timer")
    let s:scroll_timer = timer_start(s:timer_msec, funcref('s:handler'), {'repeat': -1})
  else
    call timer_stop(s:scroll_timer)
    unlet s:scroll_timer
  endif
endfunc

let s:timer_msec = 200
map <C-s> :call AutoScrollToggle()<CR>
```

Then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to toggle the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following keyboard shortcuts to scroll up and down. To continuously scroll, just hold them down.

```
k - Scroll up one line
j - Scroll down one line
Ctrl+b - Scroll up one full screen
Ctrl+f - Scroll down one full screen
Ctrl+u - Scroll up half screen
Ctrl+d - Scroll down half screen
```